# Changing volume of Radio, depending on “music” or "speaking" with Raspberry Pi and Librosa?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, librosa

My problem :
I’m listening to info-radio, where the information is important, not the music.
In Belgium, the music is always louder than the speaking.

Comment: What I already found :
Reading :
https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/652 
https://librosa.org/doc/main/ioformats.html 
Download and read from URL

Comment: Analyse :
Can I determine "music" with "tempo" and "beats" ?
https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.beat.beat_track.html